# Checking a date with three different date type libraries

Tags: python, list, date, datetime, python-dateutil

I have a list of different dates. I want to test if the value in list is valid date or not. I have tried to do it but the statement which I gave isn't working well. How do I do it?

```
list1 = ['201222020','20-12-2020','12122020', '53122020']
valid=[]
invalid=[]
for l in list1:
    try:
        x = dateutil.parser.parse(str(l)) or dt.strptime(str(l),'%m%d%Y') or dt.strptime(str(l),'%d%m%Y')
        valid.append(x)
    
    except:
        invalid.append(l)
print(valid)
print(invalid)
```

Which gives:

```
valid = [datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, 0, 0)]
invalid = ['201222020', '12122020', '53122020']
```

But in real life dates like this `'201222020','12122020'` should also be accepted, which happens by using the other statement after `or` and this value `'53122020'` should be rejected.

In my scenario it's coming as above. Where am I going wrong? How to align the statements in correct way so that the list will be checked one after the other `(first date until and then datetime('%m%d%Y')` and then `datetime('%d%m%Y')` by all three?

Actual output:

```
 valid = [datetime.datetime(2020, 20, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 0, 0)]
invalid = ['53122020']
```

Comment: Why do you want to use different libraries? As far as I can tell you only need to come up with a clear definition what is *valid* and use `strptime` in a `try/except`. Side-note: the order of month and day can lead to ambiguities - just take "01-02-2020", will parse both as mm-dd-yyyy *and* dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: @MrFuppes Dateutil can match any kind of date format either but it can't match mmddyyyy or ddmmyyyy. For that reason I am doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that tries a set of other functions to parse the input. Those latter functions could be `dateutil.parser.parse`, `datetime.strptime` or whatever you choose. If all fail, the input is invalid.

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil

def validate(datestring, vd_funcs, vd_args):
    """
    a function that tests if a datestring can be parsed by one of the functions
    supplied by vd_funcs. vd_args can be used to provide these funcs with additional
    arguments.
    """
    for f, a in zip(vd_funcs, vd_args):
        try:
            return f(datestring, *a) # see if the function works, return if so
        except ValueError:
            continue # try next
    else:
        return None # no function worked, invalid date string
    
# the functions you want to use to see if they parse the string    
vd_funcs = (dateutil.parser.parse, datetime.strptime, datetime.strptime)
# arguments to these functions, after passing the date string itself.
vd_args = ((None,), ('%m%d%Y',), ('%d%m%Y',))
```

running this for the list of example date strings gives

```
valid=[]
invalid=[]  
for s in ['201222020','20-12-2020','12122020', '53122020']:
    vd = validate(s, vd_funcs, vd_args)
    if vd:
        valid.append(vd)
    else:
        invalid.append(s)
    
valid
[datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 0, 0)]

invalid
['201222020', '53122020']
```

Comment: Thanks  for your effort simple and easy I literally wrote three try and except for each date format :)

Comment: @Rapooram: glad I could help! There are certainly other ways one could do that, I just liked the idea of a kind of functional approach. And keep in mind, sometimes a little repetition is better than being clever because it is just more readable ^^